# Issue in Cappuccino framework in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cappuccino, objective-j

I have following error in XCode

mkdir: /CappuccinoSample/test6/build/Debug: File exists
cp: /Developer/Cappuccino/Tools/cxhelper/cxhelper: No such file or directory
/CappuccinoSample/test6/build/test6.build/Debug/test6.build/Script-643C0D440E7F85EC00F64609.sh: line 4: /CappuccinoSample/test6/build/Debug/test6: No such file or directory

I try to solve it but still I do all stuff which mention here http://cappuccino.org/discuss/2008/10/01/using-xcode-to-develop-in-cappuccino/

But still I get an error

Please anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your install has messed up, or has incorrect or older files. Here is what I would do to fix it:

1. Clean up the old files (trash the /Developer/Cappuccino folder).
2. Download/extract fresh tarball from:
   https://github.com/rbartolome/xcode-cappuccino
3. Copy the following folders to location:
   /Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/
   File Templates
   Project Templates
   Specifications
   Target Templates
4. Restart xcode, and everything should be working smoothly.